# How To Log In To Google Account - api 28

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-play-services

I am trying to set a logIn/signUp to a google account. I wrote the code and it should work but it doesn't(it always ends up with the failed toast I made).

I watch a bunch of videos and looked at google doc and my code is pretty much the same.

```
protected void onStart() {
    if( getIntent().getBooleanExtra(ThirdActivity.extraLoggedIn, false) == false ) {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
        if (account != null) {
            getDataFromFirebase(account);
            //playerNameText.setText("Player Name: " + accountName);
        } else {
            startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), 0);
            //account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);
            //signUp(account);
        }
        loggedIn = true;
    }
    super.onStart();
    changeLanguage(SingletonDemiClass.getInstance().getLanguage());
    playerNameText.setText("Player Name: " + accountName);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 0){
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        //Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, task.getResult().getId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        signUp(task);
    }
}

//private void signUp(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
private void signUp(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {

    try {
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        accountID = account.getId();
        accountName = account.getDisplayName();

    }
    catch (ApiException ex) {


        Log.w("Google Sign-In Error", "signInResult:failed code=" + ex.getStatusCode());
        Toast.makeText(SecondActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //}
    }
}
```

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMfZI.png)

Comment: You should be receive some error code from google sdk. can you please post that?

Comment: Where can I see those?

Comment: In logcat, there should be some keyword related to that.

Comment: I will check, one minute.

Comment: Can't see that...

Comment: can you post your whole log cat, and not just error verbose also?

Comment: I need someone to add that to my question - I can only post it as an answer.

Comment: can't you edit your question?

Comment: The website's algorithm won't let me add this much code lines to my question.

Comment: upload 2 or 3 screenshots of that

Comment: I added to the question.

Comment: Hey, sorry but didnt get what i was looking for

Comment: Ok, I will upload another one

Comment: Maybe it's not working because the first sign in cannot be done at onStart method?